# Is copying standard definitions from e.g. ICD without quotes considered verbatim plagiarism

Tags: writing, plagiarism

In  textbooks published by my faculty staff members, Authors often include definitions from WHO or ICD using passive speech (... is defined as ...)

1. Is this legal?
2. Is copying these standard definitions without quotation marks considered as
   verbatim plagiarism ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Unfortunately, I'm having a little bit of difficulty understanding your question: what are "faculty books"?  Can you please expand the acronyms of ICD and WHO?  Do you really mean the World Health Organization or something else?

Comment: By faculty books, i mean textbooks published by the staff members , ICD (International classification of diseases),WHO(World Health organisation)

Comment: I suppose they give the reference?

Comment: @AhmedElmahy Do they say "this definition is from the ICD" or not?

Comment: ICD is a classification of diseases, it contains standard definitions. In the books published by my faculty staff members, they include these definitions using passive speech (e.g.  maternal death is defined as ...copied_text...) @jakebeal

Comment: No they don't say or cite ICD at all!

Comment: Why are you asking?  To make sure you do the right thing in your own publications?  Or to police the publications of others?

Comment: I am asking because this is very common in these textbooks, and yes if it's wrong, I want to report it.

Comment: @GEdgar Regardless of why he is asking, the question seems to be about a valid point: whether and how to reference definitions from a _copy-righted_, widely known and used, international standard classification.

Answer (score 5):

Definitions straddle a line between things that clearly require attribution and things that are "common knowledge" and do not require attribution.  For example, if I write on my own that:

> influenza is a viral disease of the respiratory system that causes fever, aches, and other symptoms

then I need not attribute any source, because this is common knowledge.  On the other hand, if I copy verbatim the Merriam-Webster definition:

> a common illness that is caused by a virus and that causes fever, weakness, severe aches and pains, and breathing problems

then even though it's almost identical, I need to attribute the source because they aren't my own words.  For such simple and widely accepted information, that attribution might not need a formal reference or even quotes, e.g.,

> The Merriam-Webster dictionary defines influenza as a common illness that is caused by a virus and that causes fever, weakness, severe aches and pains, and breathing problems.

Quotes would be better, but the attribution is still clear, so it's a minor problem at worst.

Now, how does this apply to the situations that you have described?

- First and foremost, if the definitions are being taken from standard references, the link to standard references is *valuable* for students to know, so from a pedagogical point of view they should be included even if it weren't strictly necessary.
- If a large number of definitions are being presented *specifically* as the professor's own work, when they are not, then it is clearly a case of plagiarism (albeit a particularly banal and pointless one).
- If, on the other hand, they are being presented more generally as "information about the subject", then it is more of a grey area.  They *should* be attributed, but informal material like course notes is often treated quite sloppily in practice, and it is likely to be perceived as a shortcoming to be corrected rather than a serious issue of plagiarism.

Comment: For some simple definitions, it's entirely possible that people would spontaneously produce identical definitions, especially if they're things that are repeated ad nauseam.  Although in the specific example, I'd imagine somewhere in a foreword they mention that they use the definitions as per X authority or just have a large list of references at the end of each chapter rather than just repeat "According to X" every other sentence.  I can't personally recall having had a textbook that actually cited everything along the way in text, though I'd guess some fields like law would.